# Pegar objeto dentro de String JSON

Tags: java, json, web-service

Recebo o seguinte JSON de um web service /

```
`{
“SinteseCadastral”: {
“Documento”: “99999999999”,
“Nome”: “NOM DE TESTES”,
“NomeMae”: “NOME DA MAE DE TESTE”,
“NomeFantasia”: “NOME FANTASIA DE TESTE”,
“DataNascimento”: “99/99/9999”,
“DataFundacao”: “99/99/9999”,
“SituacaoRFB”: “REGULAR”,
“SituacaoDescricaoRFB”: “REGULAR”,
“DataSituacaoRFB”: “29/04/2018 12:04:34”
},
“TotalOcorrencias”: 3,
“ValorTotalOcorrencias”: “99.999,99”,
“AlertaDocumentos”: {
“NumeroMensagem”: “1”,
“TotalMensagens”: “1”,
“TipoDocumento”: “RG”,
“NumeroDocumento”: “9999999”,
“MotivoOcorrencia”: “EXTRAVIO”,
“DataOcorrencia”: “01/01/1980”,
“TelefonesContato”: [
{
“Telefone”: “(11) 9999-9999”
}
],
“Mensagem”: “Alerta”
},
“PendenciasInternas”: {
“TotalOcorrencias”: 0,
“Mensagem”: “NAO CONSTAM OCORRENCIAS”
},
“PendenciasFinanceiras”: {
“TotalOcorrencias”: 0,
“OcorrenciaMaisAntiga”: “99/9999”,
“OcorrenciaMaisRecente”: “99/9999”,
“PendenciasFinanceirasDetalhe”: [
{
“DataOcorrencia”: “99/99/9999”,
“Modalidade”: “OO”,
“Avalista”: “N”,
“TipoMoeda”: “R$”,
“Valor”: “99.999,99”,
“Contrato”: “99999999999999”,
“Origem”: “UF”,
“Sigla”: “XX”,
“SubJudice”: “N”,
“SubJudiceDescricao”: “”,
“TipoAnotacao”: “PEFIN”,
“TipoAnotacaoDescricao”: “PENDENCIA FINANCEIRA”
}
],
“Mensagem”: “CONSTAM RESTRICOES”
},
“PendenciasBacen”: {
“TotalOcorrencias”: 9,
“OcorrenciaMaisAntiga”: “99/9999”,
“OcorrenciaMaisRecente”: “99/9999”,
“Banco”: “999”,
“Agencia”: “9999”,
“NomeFantasiaBanco”: “NOME FANTASIA DO BANCO”,
“PendenciasBacenDetalhe”: [
{
“DataOcorrencia”: “99/99/9999”,
“NumeroCheque”: “9999999”,
“AlineaCheque”: “99”,
“QuantidadeCCFBanco”: “9”,
“Valor”: “99.999,99”,
“Banco”: “999”,
“NomeBanco”: “NOME FANTASIA DO BANCO”,
“Agencia”: “999”,
“Cidade”: “CIDADE”,
“UF”: “UF”
}
],
“Mensagem”: “EXISTEM RESTRICOES”
},
“RiskScore”: {},
“LimiteCredito”: {},
“Mensagem”: “Transacao realizada com sucesso”,
“Status”: true,
“Transacao”: {
“Status”: true,
“CodigoStatus”: “G000M001”,
“CodigoStatusDescricao”: “Transacao realizada com sucesso”
}
}`
```

E preciso pegar os seguintes dados desse json “Sintese Cadastral”, “PendenciasBacen” , “Pendencias financeiras” e colocar em objetos de suas respectivas classes. Alguém tem ideia de como posso fazer isso? Usando qualquer uma das diversas bibliotecas que existem para parse de json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma biblioteca chamada Jackson, que faz a serialização (objeto para json) e a deserialização (json para objeto):

[Documentação do Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs)

Basicamente, você precisa:

1) Adicionar o jar do Jackson ao seu projeto.

2) Criar um mapeamento de classes que reflita o seu json, utilizando annotations para direcionar o processo de deserialização.

3) Deserializar usando a classe [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) do Jackson.

Um pequeno exemplo que serve para você entender e dar seguimento à sua necessidade. A classe Dados tem alguns atributos, entre eles uma classe Departamento. Eis o json:

```
{
  "nome":"jose da silva",
  "idade": 40,
  "data": "25-04-2018",
  "departamento": {
    "codigo": "alfa"
  }
}
```

A seguir, o mapeamento de classes que reflete a estrutura do json. Veja a anotação sobre a variável do tipo Date, para informar ao json o formato esperado:

```
class Dados {

    private String nome;
    private int idade;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private Date data;

    private Departamento departamento;
    //getters e setters

}

class Departamento {
    private String codigo;
    //getters e setters
```

Finalmente, o código para efetivamente deserializar o json em um objeto do tipo Dados:

```
Dados dados = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Dados.class);
```

Se essa resposta ajudou você, marque-a como a correta, ok?