# Como converter JSON em Objeto e encontrar um id - JAVA

Tags: java, json

Preciso converter um JSON em objeto e navegar até um ID e capturar apenas ele.
JSON Exemplo:

```
"{"_status":"sucesso","_dados":{"_sucesso":[{"idintegracao":"BkmRboZmaaa","situacao":"SALVO","TituloNumeroDocumento":"01012020","TituloNossoNumero":"501","CedenteContaCodigoBanco":"748","CedenteContaNumero":"9999","CedenteConvenioNumero":"9999"}],"_falha":[]}}
```

Preciso capturar o idIntegração que fica em _dados._sucesso[0].idintegracao, e salvar em uma string.
O que fiz até agora:

```
 String jsonString = response.body().string();

        JSONObject jsonObjectBoleto = new JSONObject("{" + jsonString + "}");


        Iterator<String> iteratorBoletos = jsonObjectBoleto.keys();
        System.out.println("TO AQUI");

        System.out.println("TO AQUI NO WHILE " + iteratorBoletos.toString());
        JSONObject dadosBoleto = jsonObjectBoleto.getJSONObject(iteratorBoletos.toString());
        System.out.println("TO AQUI NO WHILE 2 " + iteratorBoletos.toString());
        Boleto boleto = new Boleto();
        System.out.println("DADOS DO BOLETO: " + dadosBoleto.getString("idintegracao"));
```

Tentei também fazer isso mas sem sucesso:

```
      String jsonString = response.body().string();

        String json = ("{" + jsonString + "}");

        JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(json);

        String idIntegracao = obj1.getString("idintegracao");

        System.out.println("idIntegracao : " + idIntegracao);
```

Comment: Você deve ter pesquisado libs como Jackson e Gson, e tem alguma dúvida específica, não é? Qual seria ela? Pode postar o código do que fez até agora?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Pegar objeto dentro de String JSON](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295002/pegar-objeto-dentro-de-string-json)

Comment: Você já sabe qual API de JSON você vai usar?

Comment: Está usando Spring Boot?

Comment: Para gerar as classes Java, você poderá usar algum gerador JSON to Java Classes.
http://json2java.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Postei o que fiz até agora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar utilizar a API de processamento de Json disponível apartir do java 1.8

Dependencias maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
     <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Após adicionar as bibliotecas recupere o Json em uma String e crie um JsonReader para ler a String:

```
String jsonString = response.readEntity(String.class);
JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(jsonString));
```

Recupere o JsonObject apartir do jsonReader:

```
 JsonObject jsonObject = jsonReader.readObject();
```

Recupere o JsonObject para o atributo "_dados"

```
 JsonObject attributeDados = jsonObject.getJsonObject("_dados");
```

Recupere o JsonArray para o atributo "_sucesso"

```
 JsonArray jsonArray = attributeDados.getJsonArray("_sucesso");
```

Recupere enfim o id

```
String idIntegracao = jsonArray.getJsonObject(0).getString("idintegracao");
```

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela resposta, mais tive um nullPointer neste linha
            javax.json.JsonArray jsonArray = attributeDados.getJsonArray("_sucesso");

Comment: Ao testar verifiquei que o erro está na linha onde recupera o id, substituia "getJsonObject(1)" por "getJsonObject(0)"

Comment: Fiz a alteração mais o erro insiste na linha de cima, onde esta o _sucesso.

Comment: Cara o Json estava passando nullo, verifiquei e deu certo, muito obrigado :D